# Doxygen; Customize header output file

Tags: css, documentation, doxygen

I'm using Doxygen v1.8.13 on Windows.

I'm trying to optimize our HTML output. I would like to have the header with the navbar and search input stick on the top of the pages.

Using a custom css I managed to give the needed tags a position of `fixed` and all is working fine, except for the search results. That div (with an iframe) is falling behind my `div.header`. 
When I move the `div.header` block inside the `div.top` block everything works as expected.

But I can't modify this in the `header.html` template, because the `div.header` block is not included.

How to solve this?

Here's my CSS, if needed:

```
/* Make the header fixed at the top */
#top {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  top: 137px;
}

  .header > div.summary {
    padding-right: 25px;
  }

div.headertitle {
  padding: 5px 5px 0 10px;
}

  div.headertitle > .title {
    margin: 0 2px;
  }

div.contents {
  margin-top: 180px;
}

#MSearchResultsWindow {
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

@media(max-width:768px) {
  .header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    top: 277px;
  }

  div.contents {
    margin-top: 318px;
  }
}
```

[image: The output with the search result box partially hidden by the header]

I already read these similar questions:

- [Remove Doxygen prototype header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47728756/remove-doxygen-prototype-header)
- [Provide custom/configurable HTML templates to Doxygen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46976382/provide-custom-configurable-html-templates-to-doxygen)

But they don't provide what I need.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using 1.8.13 on Windows, which, I think, is the latest version. I can however move to any other version if it would solve my problem.

Comment: Problem looks like to be related to the fixed positioning settings. I don't see why this is necessary for all items / necessary at all. Wouldn't it be possible to use a fixed size for the top part (with the logo).

Comment: When I don't set the header to fixed I, indeed, don't have this problem but then the header (with the class name) scrolls out of view or isn't even visible when the page was opened/loaded using a # link. 
But it seems other solutions are not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working. Instead of using `position: absolute` I'm now using `flex-box`. I also needed to add a new `div` around all other divs.

This is my css code:

```
html,
body,
#page {
  height: 100%; /* needed for proper layout */
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#top {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.header {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

div.contents {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  position: relative; /* need this to position inner content */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

div.footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

And this is the live website: http://www.mapwindow.org/documentation/mapwingis4.9/index.html